# php, file character

Tags: php, file

Is there way to replace last charcter in each line within file using php?

I have file that has bunch of lines and at the end of each line there is a character that I need to remove.

Do I have to read file line by line or is there magic that I can use to strip last character in each line of a file?

How would I do that?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the character the same character every time? You can load your file into a string using

```
$mystr = file_get_contents("myfile.txt");
```

and then use preg_replace to remove your character from the string.

```
$mystr = preg_replace("yourcharhere","",$mystr);
```

and then put your string back into the file

```
$fh = fopen("myfile.txt", 'w');
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```

You can also add yourcharacterhere+newline in the preg_replace and then cahnge the "" to a newline. That will make it so it only removes your character before a newline. If you have different characters you need to remove, you can use a regular expression and a wildcard to remove any character before a newline.

Comment: so, going off of everyones response I came up with this solution:

Preg replace was not helping, It was replacing much of the string which I didn't want and since I needed to stip off last char I skipped on regular expression.

 
   **$myArray = explode("\n", $mystr);**

loop through myArray and update the value like below and recreate myArray with same key and new value:

   **$val = substr_replace($val ,"",-1);**

works like a charm. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

You are going to have to read in each line and edit each line with.  What OS are you using?  Unix has some useful tools (awk, sed) for this type of problem.

Comment: I am using php but I believe I can do system calls within php script if there is better way then going through line by line.

Comment: What is the reason that you don't want to just edit each line as it comes in?

Comment: no reason. I was only asking. It doesn't come as each line. It comes as a file and I have to edit/update the file to remove the last character from each line. Was just wondering if one way was better than other thats all :)

Comment: Fair enough :)  Best of luck!!

Answer (score 0):

You would either have to read the file line by line, or load the entire file and then explode it by a linebreak and then loop through that (essentially the same).